# Photon Scattering - How is the cancellation of logarithmic divergence related to gauge invariance?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-invariance

Reading the introduction to QFT by David Tong, I came across the following comment:

[image]

After a quick search, I came across an article that covers the calculational details of this cancellation: ["Light-Light Scattering"
by Naohiro Kanda](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0592). But unfortunately the article does not draw the connection to gauge invariance, that has been stated by Tong. So my question is: Why is this cancellation not accidental, but rather a consequence of gauge invariance?

Comment: See Schwartz, Section 21.1.1. It relies on the Ward identity, which is equivalent to gauge invariance here.

Comment: The argument Schwartz gives is quite nice, thank you for the reference! One elementary step in it isn't quite obvious to me: Why does the amplitude have to be linear in the polarisations? Apart from this: The argument that Schwartz uses is more or less an elegant calculation, which connects the cancellation of the various terms to the Ward identity and thus to gauge invariance. But is there a deeper direct connection / underlying principle that might hold for scattering of gauge bosons beyond QED?